# Changing File Names in Subfolder

Tags: windows-10, powershell

is there a way to modify this so that it will rename everything in a folder that has a folder?

```
get-childitem *.txt |
    ForEach {
        Move-Item -LiteralPath $_.name $_.name.Replace("old","new")
        }
```

For example, if I want to change a file named example (1).mp3 to example.mp3 in a folder called Example, how can I adapted it to do all the subfolders that exist in Example.

Comment: It's odd to use `Move-Item to rename but not move files. Did you write this or copy from the internet? Edit you question to provide a better understanding of folder structure & sample data.

Comment: First, why are you no using rename-item? There is no need to move. As for [how can I adapted it to do all the subfolders that exist in Example] that is what the -Recurse switch is for when using cmdlets like Get-ChildItem. See the help files for details and examples.

Comment: I got the code from someone in this post, it has worked pretty well so far but will edit it if it makes sense to do so.

-Recurse I tried to add it in but I can't figure out where it would fit in this code, I tried get-childitem *.mp3 -recurse | ForEach { Move-Item -LiteralPath $_.name $_.name.Replace(" (0).mp3",".mp3")} but it threw up errors